# Difficulty finding Expectation of a special function

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, mathematica

I have a special function given as:

$${\rm f}\left(r\right) ={1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
\exp\left({\left[2^{r/\beta} - 1\right]K \over \lambda}\right)$$

I should find the Expectation of the random variable $r$. Mathematica was not able to solve the associated Integral function. So it returns:

$$ \int_0^{\infty}\left\{{1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
\exp\left({\left[2^{r/\beta} - 1\right]K \over \lambda}\right)\right\}\ r\,{\rm d}r $$

Does anyone recognize how I can reduce this function so I can solve it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_0^{\infty}\braces{{1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
\exp\pars{{\bracks{2^{r/\beta} - 1}K \over \lambda}}}\ r\,\dd r:\ {\large ?}}$
and we'll assume $\ds{{K \over \lambda} < 0}$.

> Let's $\ds{t \equiv -\,{\bracks{2^{r/\beta} - 1}K \over \lambda}}$ such that
>   $\ds{r = {\beta\ln\pars{1 - \lambda t/K} \over \ln\pars{2}}}$
>   and $\ds{\dd r = {-\lambda/K \over \ln\pars{2}\pars{1 - \lambda t/K}}\,\dd t}$:

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty}\braces{{1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
\exp\pars{{\bracks{2^{r/\beta} - 1}K \over \lambda}}}\ r\,\dd r
\\[3mm]&={1 \over \beta\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{1 - {\lambda \over K}\,t}\expo{-t}\,
{{\beta\ln\pars{1 - \lambda t/K} \over \ln\pars{2}}}\,
{-\lambda/K \over \ln\pars{2}\pars{1 - \lambda t/K}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over K\ln^{2}\pars{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{1 + \mu t}\expo{-t}
\,\dd t\qquad\mbox{where}\qquad\mu \equiv -\,{\lambda \over K} > 0.
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}
> &\int_0^{\infty}\braces{{1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
> \exp\pars{{\bracks{2^{r/\beta} - 1}K \over \lambda}}}\ r\,\dd r
> =-\,{1 \over K\ln^{2}\pars{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\,
> {\mu \over 1 + \mu t}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{\expo{1/\mu} \over K\ln^{2}\pars{2}}\int_{1/\mu}^{\infty}
> {\expo{-t} \over t}\,\dd t
> ={\expo{1/\mu} \over K\ln^{2}\pars{2}}\,{\rm E_{i}}\pars{-\,{1 \over \mu}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm E_{i}}\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Exponential Integral Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_0^{\infty}\braces{{1 \over \beta\lambda}\,2^{r/\beta}
\exp\pars{{\bracks{2^{r/\beta} - 1}K \over \lambda}}}\ r\,\dd r
={\expo{-K/\lambda} \over K\ln^{2}\pars{2}}\,
{\rm E_{i}}\pars{K \over \lambda}}\,,\quad {K \over \lambda} < 0
$$

Comment: Thanks to Felix Marin who made me aware of a typo in my own answer. There is still a mismatch : $\beta$ in my result is not in Martin's result.

Comment: Fine. Any way it's nice to have different approaches. Thanks.

Comment: Felix and @JJacquelin: I thank you both for your help and time. It's clear the main problem I'm having is in the assumptions. My model assumes $K>=1$ and $\lambda >=0$.

Comment: @Methyl : With positive $K$ and $\lambda$ the integral is not convergent. So, the writting of the integral is not correct or there is something wrong in the modeling.

Comment: @JJacquelin Unless the upper limit is finite in the OP model.

Comment: @ Felix Martin : Of course. That might be the wrong point in the Methyl's modeling.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is not convergent if $K$ and $\lambda$ are positive constants.

[image]

If the upper boundary of the integral is not infinity, but $R$, the result is :

[image]

convenient in case of $K>0$ and $\lambda >0$ and finite $R$.